# Am I misundertanding the data-uri function in less

Tags: svg, less, data-uri

I'm trying to use the less data-uri function

http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-data-uri

```
.test {background-image:data-uri("/images/ui-baseline.svg");}
```

I expected it to compile a base64 background image

```
.test {   background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAgNDAiID48cmVjdCB5PSIzOSIgZmlsbD0iI0ZGODBDQiIgd2lkdGg9IjUiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIvPjxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiM4MERERkYiIGQ9Ik01LDM1SDB2LTFoNVYzNXogTTUsMzBIMHYtMWg1VjMweiBNNSwyNUgwdi0xaDVWMjV6IE01LDIwSDB2LTFoNVYyMHogTTUsMTVIMHYtMWg1VjE1eiBNNSwxMEgwVjloNVYxMHogTTUsNUgwVjRoNVY1eiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==); }
```

However I can't seem to get this to work.
The compiled output is:

```
.test {
  background-image: url("/images/ui-baseline.svg");
}
```

Have I missed something?
Does the function accept root relative paths?

I'm using Koala and it up to date using less 1.7

Thanks

Comment: Most likely the problem is in the path (`data-uri` falls back to `url` if it cannot find specified file). The relative path would be `"images/ui-baseline.svg"` w/o leading slash.

Comment: Would that be relative to the less file or to my css file?

Comment: By default it is relative to the directory of the master less file (i.e. the one you actually compile). (Also note that compiler is unaware of any "root relative paths" since it has no idea where your site root will be at the time of compilation). See [related options](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-rootpath) though (But I can't remember if any of those can affect `data-uri`).

Comment: I tried that, but still no joy. After a little more reading, I think ieCompat is on by default, I checked the available docs in Koala. It suggested altering the project setting (ctrl + click/right click on a project), but I'm not sure what I'm doing atthat point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

the problem was Koala requires a local install of less.

https://github.com/oklai/koala/issues/262#issuecomment-49688887